array_replace_recursive(): Argument #2 must be of type array, int given
При попытке зарегистрировать пользователя выдает ошибку при валидации, сама ошибка в шапке.

Честно, не понимаю почему это происходит, учитывая, что до этого на локальном сервере это все отрабатывало, а развернув на хостинге замечаю такую картину. На локальном сервере стоит php 8.1, на сервере уже 8.3, при этом ничего в функции не поменялось.

С холодной головой полез в конфиг php, решил проблему путем включения короткого синтаксиса.
